# React Router Navigate Issue in Semantic Ui React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have an issue with navigating pages via Route.
I used semantic ui react components to handle with the issue.

When I link any item in navbar, the url is changed like http://localhost:3000/ to http://localhost:3000/list but the relevant component page cannot open.

How can I fix it?

Here is my index.js code shown below.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is my App.js code shown below.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container style={{"marginTop": "20px"}}>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/">
          <AccordionComponent items={items} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/list">
          <Search />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dropdown">
          <DropdownForm options={options}/>;
        </Route>
        <Route path="/translate">
          <Translate />
        </Route>

      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Route Component shown below.

```
const Route = ({ path, children }) => {
    return window.location.pathname === path ? children : null;
  };
  
export default Route;
```

Here is my Header Component shown below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {

  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState('Accordion');

  const handleItemClick = (name) => setActiveItem(name)

  return (
    <Menu secondary pointing>
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link} to="/"
          name='Accordion'
          active={activeItem === 'Accordion'}
          onClick={() => handleItemClick('Accordion')}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link} to="/list"
          name='Search'
          active={activeItem === 'Search'}
          onClick={() => handleItemClick('Search')} 
        />
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link} to="/dropdown"
          name='Dropdown'
          active={activeItem === 'Dropdown'}
          onClick={() => handleItemClick('Dropdown')} 
        />
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link} to="/translate"
          name='Translate'
          active={activeItem === 'Translate'}
          onClick={() => handleItemClick('Translate')}
        />
      </Menu>

  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap de routes with Switch as this example:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container style={{"marginTop": "20px"}}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <AccordionComponent items={items} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/list">
          <Search />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dropdown">
          <DropdownForm options={options}/>;
        </Route>
        <Route path="/translate">
          <Translate />
        </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: The relevant component cannot be opened.

Comment: @TonyBrand i dont understand your created Route component, Route is a component from the react-router-dom library, it could may conflict having the same name?

Comment: I also used Route from react-router but it didn't work.

Comment: @TonyBrand you used the Route from react-router wrapped with the Switch component and didnt work... And maybe some kind of error in the import or export... Can you provide an example in codeSandbox to play with?

Comment: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`